# Cannot publish to Azure using web deploy - after email from MS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, azure, azure-web-roles

I get this email from Microsoft:

> This mail is confirmation that you successfully changed your
>   subscription to BizSpark Plus on Thursday, December 12, 2013. Please
>   retain a copy of this for your records.

And now I cannot publish to Azure using web deploy.  Below is the error:

> Error 32  Web deployment task failed. (Connected to the remote computer
>   ("X.cloudapp.net") using the Web Management Service, but could not
>   authorize. Make sure that you are using the correct user name and
>   password, that the site you are connecting to exists, and that the
>   credentials represent a user who has permissions to access the site. 
>   Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED.)       0   0   X.API

I've tried to import a new .publishsettings file but it keeps throwing the same errors.  Has anyone fought with this before and gotten to resolution?  Or any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Congrats on BizSpark Plus! I'd check in the portal, maybe your certificates for management were deleted somehow? Might need to download another public settings file.

The forums on the Windows Azure site if you opened this same question might be better since actual MS support folks can look into your account from there.

Comment: @JeffWilcox I'm starting to think you are correct about the cert deletion.  Appreciate the note...